How to get strings within square brackets [] in the declarations line and their related import strings
In a text file which has the line beginning with the "declarations:" string,
replace "declarations" with "imports",
replace "AppComponent" or "NxWelcomeComponent" with "",
parse the result string to get the individual string separated by comma ",",
and get their related import strings from above.
e.g.
in:
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import { Test2 } from './test2';
import { Test3 } from './test';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NxWelcomeComponent, ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test2],
})

Expected out:
import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import { Test2 } from './test2';

imports: [ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test2],

I tried:
test.awk:
/declarations:/ {str=$0;  sub("declarations", "imports", str) ; sub("AppComponent,", "", str) ; sub("NxWelcomeComponent,", "", str) }
/import/ { importbuf[++arrindex]=$0}

END {
    for (i in importbuf) {
        print importbuf[i]
    }
    print str
}

awk -f test.awk in


Extra input in2:
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import {Test4} from './test4';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NxWelcomeComponent, ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test4],
})

Expected out2:
import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import {Test4} from './test4';

imports: [ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test4],

awk -f test.awk in2


are these the only lines in your input files? are there other lines (not shown) that need to be maintained and if so, please update the question to include examples of said lines; the current answer, while it generates the desired result, is going to discard any other lines that occur in the input file ... it's not clear from what's been presented (so far) if this is what you want

Why does RouterModule disappear from the expected output?

You may use this 2 pass awk solution.
cat imports.awk

NR == FNR {
   if ($1 ~ /^declarations/) {
      gsub(/[[:blank:]]*declarations[^[]*\[|].*/, "")
      n = split($0, tok, /[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*/)
      for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
         imports[tok[i]]
   }
   next
}
/^[[:blank:]]*import/ {
   s = $0
   gsub(/^[[:blank:]]*import[^{]*{ *| *}.*/, "")
   if ($0 in imports) {
      print s
      pimports[++k] = $0
   }
}

END {
   printf "\nimports: ["
   for (i=1; i<=k; ++i)
      printf "%s", (i>1 ? ", " : "") pimports[i]
   print "],"
}

Then use it as:
awk -f imports.awk in in

import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import { Test2 } from './test2';

imports: [ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test2],

Or for the 2nd example:
awk -f imports.awk in2 in2

import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import {Test4} from './test4';

imports: [ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test4],


I added extra input in2 which will get expected out2.

@ anubhava, Thanks!
Would you mind explaining the purpose of:
for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
imports[tok[i]]

That loop is looping through tok array that is indexed by positions 1,2,3... into imports array that will have keys as: ScrollDirective,TestComponent,Test4

As an alternative, you can use Ruby with a regex and set arithmetic on the arrays from the regex.
With your two examples as file_1 and file_2 try:
$ cat rprog 
# read file
inp=$<.read

# create hash of stuff_between_braces=everything up to ;
imports=inp.scan(/^(\s*import\b\s*{\s*([^}\s]+)\s*}[^;]*;)/).map(&:reverse).
    to_h

# get declarations and the list that follows
declarations=inp.match(/^\s*declarations:\s*\[([^\]]+)\]/)[1].split(/\s*,\s*/)

# intersection between hash keys and decl list is your goal
(imports.keys & declarations).each{|k| puts imports[k] }
puts "\nimports: [#{(imports.keys & declarations).join(", ")}]\n"

Then run that program:
ruby rprog file_1

Prints:
import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import { Test2 } from './test2';

imports: [ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test2]

Or your second example:
ruby rprog file_2

Prints:
import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import {Test4} from './test4';

imports: [ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test4]

The major advantage of this approach, rather than a more traditional line oriented approach with awk, is that you can handle multiline inputs such as:
import { TestComponent } 
    from './test';

and
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NxWelcomeComponent, 
    ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test2],
})


This might work for you although it is not awk (GNU sed):
sed '/\n/bb
     /^import {/{:a;N;/^})/M!ba
    :b;/^import/{
       /^import {\s*\(\S\+\)\s*}.*\1/{
          H;x;s/import {\s*//;s/\s*} .*//;x;P}
      D}
    x;s/\n/&imports: [/;s//,/2g;s/$/]/}' file

Ignore the first line for the moment.
Gather up the requisite lines in the pattern space.
If the first line begins import carry on.
If the current lines import is present more than once in the gathered up lines i.e. also present in the declarations, append it to the hold space then after amending the hold space to contain only that declaration, print the first line.
If the first line begins import delete the first line.
Now the presence of the first line of the sed script comes into view.
Since more that one line has been gathered up, newlines are present in the pattern space. The use of the D command retains these lines after the first of them has been deleted. Thus the D command and the presence of newlines can be used as a loop mechanism to iterate through the pattern space a line at a time.
If the the first line does not begin with import we are done.
Swap to the hold space, and build an imports line using the already seen declarations.

For gawk 4.0+, if the names of the imported modules contain just words, then setting up FPAT="\\w+" (or FPAT="[[:alnum:]_]+") so that each word stands out as a FIELD can make it easier to control the imports list and the processing logic based on the value of $1:
$ cat test.awk

BEGIN{ FPAT="[[:alnum:]_]+" }

$1 == "import" { imp[$2] = $0 }
$1 == "declarations" {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($i in imp && $i !~ /^AppComponent|NxWelcomeComponent$/) {
         print imp[$i]
         ret = ret sp $i; sp = ", "
      }
   printf("\nimports [%s],\n", ret)
}

run this with your sample-2:
$ awk -f test.awk in2
import { ScrollDirective } from './directives/scroll.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test';
import {Test4} from './test4';

imports [ScrollDirective, TestComponent, Test4],

